# Using optim.step() with Pytorch's DataLoader

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

Usually the learning cycle contains:

```py
optim.zero_grad()
loss(m, op).backward()
optim.step()
```

But what should be the cycle when the data does not fit in the graphics card?

First option:

```py
for ip, op in DataLoader(TensorDataset(inputs, outputs),
                          batch_size=int(1e4), pin_memory=True):
    m = model(ip.to(dev))
    op = op.to(dev)
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss(m, op).backward()
    optim.step()
```

Second option:

```py
optim.zero_grad()
for ip, op in DataLoader(TensorDataset(inputs, outputs),
                          batch_size=int(1e4), pin_memory=True):
    m = model(ip.to(dev))
    op = op.to(dev)
    loss(m, op).backward()
optim.step()
```

The third option:
Accumulate gradients after calling backward().

Answer (score 0):

The **first option** is correct and corresponds to *batch gradient descent*.

The second option will not work because `m` and `op` are being overwritten at each step, so your optimizer step will only correspond to optimizing based on the final batch.

Comment: > backward() - This function accumulates gradients in the leaves - you might need to zero them before calling it.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.backward
"accumulates gradients" == Second option ?

Comment: Gradients are accumulated through the graph at each step. It will require far less memory on your graphics card to simply perform a backwards pass at each step instead of storing gradient information for the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of training a model using [Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) is following these steps:

1. instantiate a model, and randomly init its weights. This is done *only once*.
2. instantiate the dataset and the dataloader, defining appropriate `batch_size`.
3. Iterate over the all examples, batch by batch. At each iteration
   3.a Compute a stochastic estimate of the loss using only a batch, rather than the entire set (aka "forward pass")
   3.b Compute the gradient of the loss w.r.t the model's parameters (aka "backward pass")
   3.c Update the weights based on the current gradient

This is how the code should look like

```py
model = MyModel(...)  # instantiate a model once
dl = DataLoader(TensorDataset(inputs, outputs), batch_size=int(1e4), pin_memory=True)
for ei in range(num_epochs):
  for ip, op in dl:
    optim.zero_grad()
    predict = model(ip.to(dev))  # forward pass
    loss = criterion(predict, op.to(dev)) # estimate current loss
    loss.backward()  # backward pass - propagate gradients
    optim.step()  # update the weights based on current batch
```

Note that during training you iterate several times over the entire training set. Each such iteration is usually referred to as an "epoch".